# Which selector to use in html function in rvest package in R?

Tags: html, r, parsing, rvest

I would like to parse HTML page containing such informations:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tajemnica Oscara Pistoriusa - Książki - WP.PL</title>
<meta name="description" content="Wieczorem, 13 lutego 2013 roku ona pisze dla niego kartkę na walentynki: &lt;b&gt;&quot;Dziś jest dobry dzień, by powiedzieć, że Cię kocham&quot;.&lt;/b&gt; Zanim on odczyta tę wiadomość, ona od kilku godzin nie..." />
<meta name="keywords" content="ksiazki, książka, literatura, czytelnik" />
<meta name="language" content="pl" />
<meta name="author" content="Grupa Wirtualna Polska" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
```

And I am using `rvest` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) in R. When I use such code, with this selector: `"meta"`

```
library(rvest)

content <- html("http://ksiazki.wp.pl/gid,17325376,tytul,Tajemnica-Oscara-Pistoriusa,galeria.html?ticaid=1147a0&_ticrsn=3")

nodesS <- html_nodes(content, "meta")
```

I recieve a list of all metas, but I am interested only in one specific.
Which selector should I use to download only those informations from `content` in here:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="ksiazki, książka, literatura, czytelnik" />
```

*EDIT*:
Can anyone knows how to set `encoding` argument properly?
I received bad encoding while specifying it like this:

```
> content <- html("http://ksiazki.wp.pl/gid,17325376,tytul,Tajemnica-Oscara-Pistoriusa,galeria.html?ticaid=1147a0&_ticrsn=3", 
+                 encoding = "UTF-8" )
> 
> nodesS <- html_nodes(content, "meta[name=keywords]")
> html_attrs(nodesS)[[1]][2]
                                    content 
"ksiazki, ksiÄ…ĹĽka, literatura, czytelnik"
```

EDIT:

I found functions `guess_encoding()` and `repair_encoding()` in the overview of this readme.me on hadley's github project 
https://github.com/hadley/rvest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your CSS selector to include an [attribute value selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
nodesS <- html_nodes(content, "meta[name=keywords]")
```

You could then extract just the `content` attribute by adding:

```
html_nodes(content, "meta[name=keywords]") %>% html_attr("content")
# [1] "ksiazki, książka, literatura, czytelnik"
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for help. Do you maybe know how to set encdoing argument properly? I've edited my question.

Comment: @MarcinKosinski This seems like an entirely different question: perhaps you should ask it as a new one?

Comment: I found functions "guess_encoding() and repair_encoding()" in the overview of this readme.me on hadley's github project https://github.com/hadley/rvest